# Is there a way to lock individual cells (not the entire Excel worksheet) to prevent formatting?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm preventing the user from formatting cells in a worksheet in a generated Excel file by executing this code:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet("sheet1");
CTSheetProtection prot = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetProtection();
prot.setFormatCells(true);
```

Is there a way to lock formatting for individual cells in a sheet as opposed to having to lock formatting for the entire sheet?

Likewise, is there a way to apply the other protections to individual cells?

For example, filtering and sorting - if someone tried to apply these operations on a group of cells that included a cell that was locked for that operation it would be disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

In the Format Cells dialog box you can toggle cells locked or hidden. When you use "Protect Sheet" From the Review tab you can choose to protect the worksheet and the contents of locked cells, and choose what you want to allow the user to do to locked/unlocked cells. Password protect the sheet and users will not be able to remove the lock without your permission.

I'm assuming most of your cells are to be unlocked, so select all cells and set to unlocked and then lock the ones you want locked.

I am unsure of the code to do this through VBA, but it should be easy enough to find.
Logically, you would want to select all cells and then set the cells.format.protection.locked to false, and then select the ranges you want locked and set those to true. You could easily record a macro to find this code.

Comment: If I try more or less what you say, run Excel on my desktop and only protect some cells and then protect the sheet, formatting is disabled for all cells, locked or unlocked. Which leads me to believe there is no way to lock down formatting for locked cells only. It seems you can only disable formatting for the whole sheet. Hoping someone proves me wrong with a code example.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Didn't realize the setting said formatting for all cells, not just protected. Could you programmatically force the cells to be a certain format, no matter what a user tries to do to it? Similar to how if you conditionally format a cell''s fill color, you can't manually change it.

Comment: Not sure, I will experiment with that a little bit, seems like a possible workaround. I'd prefer the cleanest, most straightforward way of accomplishing it, but obviously some way that works is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you should check this link, I have written a custom method to lock individual or range of cells in single or multi sheet excel file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63299413/6835092

for single cell locking just mention same range value. i.e a1:a1. this will lock only a1 cell.