# Unable to lock columns in an excel sheet - xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to lock only a few columns of a excel sheet using xlsx writer. The writer has already generated worksheets from taking panda dataframes and converting them using to_excel.

When using the simple lock and protect of xlsxwriter (found [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_protection.html), the whole sheet ends up locked instead of the specific cells from the columns I've selected. Here is my code:

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('workbook.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df2.to_excel(writer, 'Except', index=False, header=False)
df1.to_excel(writer, 'Rec', index=False, header=False)
workbook = writer.book
rec_sheet = writer.sheets['Rec']
except_sheet = writer.sheets['Except']

# adding lock/unlock capabilities
locked_format = workbook.add_format()
locked_format.set_locked(True)  
unlocked_format= workbook.add_format()
unlocked_format.set_locked(False)

# unlocking columns that need to remain unlocked
rec_sheet.set_column('AC:AD', None, unlocked_format)
except_sheet.set_column('AC:AD', None, unlocked_format)

# Enable worksheet protection
except_sheet.protect()
rec_sheet.protect()
#lock columns that need to remain locked
rec_sheet.set_column('A:AB', None, locked_format)
except_sheet.set_column('A:AB', None, locked_format)
```

I expect the final workbook.xlsx to have two sheets that have columns locked up until column AC.

Comment: Have you checked this link? 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885097/xlsxwriter-lock-only-specific-cells

Comment: The code above works for me when I add some sample data frames. The cells up to column AC are locked, the cells after are unlocked.

Comment: @jmcnamara It is not working for me and  when I click on a cell that should be unlocked (AC3), it gives me this error message : "The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet. To make a change, unprotect the sheet. You might be requested to enter a password." when i unprotect the sheet, all cells are editable.

Comment: @suhas_Pete I have seen that link and has not solved my problem. here I am selecting from a dataframe and not directly writing.

Answer (score 2):

It should work. I added some sample dataframes to your example and I was able to write to cell AC3 (but not AB3):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([10, 20, 30, 20, 15])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([10, 20, 30, 20, 15])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('workbook.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df2.to_excel(writer, 'Except', index=False, header=False)
df1.to_excel(writer, 'Rec', index=False, header=False)
workbook = writer.book
rec_sheet = writer.sheets['Rec']
except_sheet = writer.sheets['Except']

# Adding lock/unlock capabilities.
locked_format = workbook.add_format()
locked_format.set_locked(True)  
unlocked_format= workbook.add_format()
unlocked_format.set_locked(False)

# Unlocking columns that need to remain unlocked.
rec_sheet.set_column('AC:AD', None, unlocked_format)
except_sheet.set_column('AC:AD', None, unlocked_format)

# Enable worksheet protection.
except_sheet.protect()
rec_sheet.protect()

# Lock columns that need to remain locked.
rec_sheet.set_column('A:AB', None, locked_format)
except_sheet.set_column('A:AB', None, locked_format)

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]