# xlsxwriter: lock only cell content

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to lock only then content of the cells of column 'B' in my sheet.
I do not know how to do that.

It always lock all the worksheet -I can not add filter or change width/heidth of cells...

I help myself with thiss page:

> [XlsxWriter: lock only specific cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885097/xlsxwriter-lock-only-specific-cells)

My code:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('protection_only_B.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create some cell formats with protection properties.
unlocked = workbook.add_format({'locked': False})
locked   = workbook.add_format({'locked': True})

# Format the worksheet to unlock all cells.
worksheet.set_column('A:XDF', None, unlocked)

# Turn worksheet protection on.
worksheet.protect()

# Write a locked and an unlocked cell.
for i in range (1, 150):
    worksheet.write('B'+str(i), 'Cell is locked', locked)

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a part of the answer:

> https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#protect

However I still can not do filtering...
Even if I put "autofilter" to True...

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('protection_only_B.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create some cell formats with protection properties.
unlocked = workbook.add_format({'locked': False})
locked   = workbook.add_format({'locked': True})

# Format the worksheet to unlock all cells.
worksheet.set_column('A:XDF', None, unlocked)

print("ok1")
# Turn worksheet protection on.
worksheet.protect('abc123', {
    'objects':               False,
    'scenarios':             False,
    'format_cells':          True,
    'format_columns':        True,
    'format_rows':           True,
    'insert_columns':        False,
    'insert_rows':           False,
    'insert_hyperlinks':     False,
    'delete_columns':        False,
    'delete_rows':           False,
    'select_locked_cells':   True,
    'sort':                  True,
    'autofilter':            True,
    'pivot_tables':          False,
    'select_unlocked_cells': True,
})

print("ok2")
# Write a locked and an unlocked cell.
for i in range (1, 150):
    worksheet.write('B'+str(i), 'Cell is locked', locked)

workbook.close()
```